# Spring application Chrome prints full content of jsp file JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, google-chrome, spring-mvc, tomcat

When i run my spring web application chrome print the full content of the jsp file. Any ideas how to fix this ?

[image]

**EDIT**
I am using mixed configuration. I have copied all the configuration files for more clear.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>pc-shop</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/conf/app-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**app-config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Scanning package with configuration files -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pcshop.saas.config" />

    <!-- Application Message Bundle -->

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>WEB-INF/props/configure</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/props/sql</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/props/strings</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/props/log4j</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="60" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="msa"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="messageSource" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**WebServletApplicationInitializer**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.pcshop")
@ImportResource(value = { "/WEB-INF/conf/data-source.xml" })
public class WebServletApplicationInitializer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not post screenshot of code. And you're going to have to make a [mcve]. Also, read [ask]...

Comment: @Tunaki Please read my question and vote after that.

Comment: I think basically your **webserver** hasn't translated the JSP page into a Java servlet. Are you using Tomcat or what?

Comment: @ Ali Seyedi Yep. I am using Tomcat. I tested it with another spring app but there were no problems.

Comment: Please provide more informations like your web.xml

Comment: @Ali Seyedi I have edited my question.

Comment: @RockOrDead If you have solved this problem, please answer your question so it may be helpful for someone else.

Comment: @Ali Seyedi no i have not solve this prolem but it runs ok in internet explorer.

Comment: I have another guess: Please try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and see if it works (I know it looks unlikely but give it a try.)